# Extract strings from xml

Tags: xml, bash

From the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <broker xmlns="some-ns.com" name="some-ns">
    <queue name="US.PUT.INTERNAL.FULFILLMENT.REMEDY" enable="true" process="/u/is/bin/RmdyCrtUtil.sh" />
    <queue name="US.DATA.MINING.IN" enable="true" process="/u/is/bin/ferret_trigger" />
    <queue name="US.PHOTO.INPUT" enable="true" process="/u/is/bin/spx0400b.sh" />
    <queue name="US.OPTICAL.INPUT" enable="true" process="/u/applic/optical/svc_web_proc.sh" />
    <queue name="US.TLGO.DATA.QUEUE" enable="true" process="/u/is/smb0010b.sh" />
</broker>
```

I want to extract the following:

```
US.PUT.INTERNAL.FULFILLMENT.REMEDY
US.DATA.MINING.IN
US.PHOTO.INPUT
US.OPTICAL.INPUT
US.TLGO.DATA.QUEUE
/u/is/bin/RmdyCrtUtil.sh
/u/is/bin/ferret_trigger
/u/is/bin/spx0400b.sh
/u/applic/optical/svc_web_proc.sh
/u/is/smb0010b.sh
```

Comment: Care to show us what you have tried?

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions in the `regex` tag if you want to extract simple data following a simple, specific format. Something like `<queue .*name="(.*?)" .*process="(.*?)"` can be a good start to solve your problem. If your input files can have any format, [there is a famous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) that addresses that point

Comment: I suggest to use an XML parser.

Comment: using bash tools, the complicated cases are prone to failure

Comment: Removed irrelevant root attributes for readability, made namespace more readable. Fixed bad syntax in attributes. Fixed grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For given data and as instant solution you can use this:

`cat test.xml |grep '<queue'|cut -d '"' -f2` - will give you `name` value 
`cat test.xml |grep '<queue'|cut -d '"' -f6` - will give you `process` value

---

```
$ cat test.xml |grep '<queue'|cut -d '"' -f2;cat test.xml |grep '<queue'|cut -d '"' -f6
US.PUT.INTERNAL.FULFILLMENT.REMEDY
US.DATA.MINING.IN
US.PHOTO.INPUT
US.OPTICAL.INPUT
US.TLGO.DATA.QUEUE
/u/is/bin/RmdyCrtUtil.sh
/u/is/bin/ferret_trigger
/u/is/bin/spx0400b.sh
/u/applic/optical/svc_web_proc.sh
/u/is/smb0010b.sh
```